# jquery mobile and google chrome issue error loading page

Tags: html, google-chrome, firefox, jquery-mobile

I am developing a web app with jQuery Mobile and in an html file I have a data-rel attribute of a link set to "dialog". Data-transition is set to "fade". The problem is, that after clicking a button which is linking to another html file Chrome says "Error loading page".

I found the solution for that and adding rel="external" does the job, but it destroys my "fade" transition. Firefox seems not to have this strange behaviour and links me to the desired page without having rel="external", so the transition works. I could stay with Firefox, but I'd like to test my app on different browsers.

What can I try next?

Answer (score 0):

if it is an external link then just put rel="external".I hope it would work.

```
<a href="index.html" rel="external" data-transition="flip">Home</a></li>
```